# Clicking twice when applying for a job on Careers 2.0 causes error to appear

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I wrote a cover letter and attached a PDF resume. I clicked the submit button fast twice in a row on accident and received this [image: error notice]

When I click back, it went to the "About You" section and said I had already applied for the position.

Edit: Also the cover letter I wrote and resume were submitted properly when I looked in my profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple classic double submit error. The actual error being thrown is something to the effect of "user has already applied to this job".

A simple fix of disabling the submit button once clicked is going up today.

Comment: Fix is up, you should now see the button change to disabled and the text "Submitting..." appear when clicking the final "Submit Application" button.